# Calibration of a Pfizer type hardness tester

Tags: forces, spring, measurements

I am working on testing of hardness of pellets for their hardness and crushing strength. Currently I have a Pfizer type harness tester at my disposal. It came with a default spring, which we found was too stiff. We then replaced the spring with a little softer one.

The problem is I couldn't find anything online on how to calibrate it for different springs. It's a pretty simple straightforward device which works on using a pressing the jaws and getting a reading in Newtons based on the inherent strength of the pellet.

The spring I am taking about is inside the compartment which is marked by the blue circle. How do I accurately calibrate everytime I put a spring inside? I though of using the basic putting weights to the spring method. Are there any other accurate methods of achieving this?

Any help will be appreciated.

[image: Hardness tester]

Comment: Have you tried contacting the manufacturer ?

Comment: One of my coworker brought this from amazon. The manufacturer seems to be a small company based in India. I couldn't find their website. As of now I haven't been able to contact them.